# Convert SQL Case When into IF ELSE as CASE ELSE not executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, if-statement, case

I have SQL statements like following

```
    declare @mydata nvarchar(MAX) = '';
    select @mydata = @mydata + case IsOwner when 1 then

    ----some sql statement like

                      '(select top 1 mytable.Value from ['+@TableVariableName+'] as mytable where 
['+ ColumnNames + ']=mytable.Key) as ['+ColumnNames+'],' 


    else case IsActive when 1 then 

    ----some sql statement 

    else
    ----some sql statement
    END END
```

`Every time last else statement should execute` as `case is not IsOwner or IsActive` 
But `I'm unable to else every time` , `may be because of case scope don't know`

> that's I need to convert above statement into IF ELSE

I tried like following

```
     declare @mydata nvarchar(MAX) = '';
        select @mydata = @mydata + 
        IF(IsOwner = 1) 
    BEGIN

        ----some sql statement like 
            '(select top 1 mytable.Value from ['+@TableVariableName+'] as mytable where 
['+ ColumnNames + ']=mytable.Key) as ['+ColumnNames+'],' 

        END
        else if ( IsActive = 1)
    BEGIN 

        ----some sql statement 
        END
        else
    BEGIN
        ----some sql statement
    END
```

I get Syntax errors :(

> I just want to insure that is no condition gets executed it should call last else everytime

Comment: What you want is a *dynamic* sql statement. Building dynamic sql can be tricky sometimes. [Here's an article that demonstrates how to build dynamic query inside a stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20815/Building-Dynamic-SQL-In-a-Stored-Procedure).

Comment: thanks can't I directly convert above CASE in IF ELSE , actually above query inside case statements itself generated dynamically , so bit tricky here to change

Comment: can you post some *---- some sql statement* in your question?

Comment: nested `case` sholud work. Correct the syntax error: You missed `END`(2 ENDs required for 2 cases) at the end

Comment: I did with 2 ends too may be i think inner query makes anything wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my test code according to your sample code, it returns `02` came from  the last else.

```
declare @mydata nvarchar(MAX) = ''
declare @IsOwner int = 2
declare @IsActive int = 2
select @mydata = @mydata + case @IsOwner when 1 then

'11'

else case @IsActive when 1 then 

 '21'

else  '02' end
end

select @mydata
```

So I think the problem not the case statement, may relate to the value of IsOwner and IsActive in your source table.